Pointwise equality of operators and Slice Maps
There is an implication in a paper I am reading that I can't seem to resolve.  Here is the basic set up of what is going on, since the full proof is very long.

Let $(A,\Delta)$ be a compact quantum group, and $h$ the Haar state on $A$.  I.e, $h$ satisfies $$(h \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta = (\text{id}_A \otimes h) \circ \Delta = h(\cdot)1_A.$$  Let $\lambda \in M(A \otimes \mathcal{K}(H_h))$ be the left regular corepresentation, where $H_h$ is the GNS Hilbert space coming from the usual construction of the cyclic triple $(\xi_h,\pi_h,H_h)$.  Let $v \in M(A \otimes \mathcal{K}(L))$ be a irreducible unitary corepresentation.  That is: $$v \in A \otimes \mathcal{K}(L) \cong M_n(A), \: \: v \sim \sum_{p,q} v_{pq} \otimes e_{pq}$$ where $n=\dim(L).$  Finally, let $\theta_{\eta',\xi'} \in \mathcal{K}(L,H)$ be given by $x \mapsto \langle x,\eta' \rangle \xi'$. Also note, $A$ acts on $H$ by $a\xi := \pi_h(a)\xi$. Let $\overline{v} = \sum_{p,q} v^{*}_{pq} \otimes e_{pq}$. By a string of calculations, we have for $\xi \in H$ and $\eta \in L$ that: $$(\lambda^{*}(1_A \otimes \theta_{\eta',\xi'})\overline{v})(\xi \otimes \eta) = (\lambda^{*}(\text{id}_A \otimes \omega_{\eta,\eta'})(\overline{v}))(\xi \otimes \xi').$$ $\textbf{Then the claim is that}$: $$(h \otimes \text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(L,H)})\big[\lambda^{*}(1_A \otimes \theta_{\eta',\xi'})\overline{v}\big](\eta) = (h \otimes \text{id}_{\mathcal{K}(L,H)})\big[\lambda^{*}(\text{id}_A \otimes \omega_{\eta,\eta'})(\overline{v})\big](\xi').$$

Now, I don't think the context is that important to what is going on here, it basically is asking the question that if two operators $R,S$ satisfy: $$S(\xi \otimes \eta) = R(\xi \otimes \xi')$$ then when I apply the slice map $h \otimes \text{id}$ I can conclude that: $$(h \otimes \text{id})(S)(\eta) = (h \otimes \text{id})(R)(\xi').$$  However I can't seem to prove such an implication is true.  It looks like all that is happening is the slice map is, well, 'slicing off' the "$A$-part" of $S$ which cares about evaluation at $\xi$, and similarly the slice map is 'slicing off' "the $A$-part" of $R$ that cares about the evaluation also at $\xi$, and then uses the above equality to argue the sliced version of $S,R$ must now agree in the above fashion.
Would anyone know how to solve this?

It’s slightly confusing since you seemed to have dropped the subscripts from $H_h$ and $\xi_h$, so $h(a) = \langle \xi, a\xi \rangle$, if I’m not misunderstanding?

The $\xi$ and $\xi_h$ are different vectors

So there’s no relation whatsoever between $h$ and $\xi$? Then this is definitely false. Just knowing $S(\xi \otimes \eta) = R(\xi \otimes \xi’)$ for a single $\xi$ with no connection to $h$ is certainly not enough to imply $(h \otimes \text{id})(S)(\eta) = (h \otimes \text{id})(R)(\xi’)$.
